# Overlaying clustering results on an ordination

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, hclust, vegan

I need to overlay the clusters generated from cutting a dendrogram a given level of similarity onto an ordination result (NMDS). I have been looking through ade4 and vegan without finding any obvious solutions to this problem.

I am current using Primer-e (see screen shot below) but am finding the graphics a bit limited. Any point in the right direction is greatly appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

This is quite easy with **vegan** and I have a [blog post](http://www.fromthebottomoftheheap.net/?p=437) that explains some of this in detail, but not the bit about the clustering.

Here is a quick example, I will assume you can translate this to whatever packages/code you are using.

Load the package and data set

```
require(vegan)
data(dune)
```

Compute the dissimilarity matrix and cluster it, cutting the dendrogram to give 3 groups

```
dij <- vegdist(dune) ## bray curtis dissimilarity
clu <- hclust(dij, method = "average")
grp <- cutree(clu, 3)
```

Look at `grp`

```
R> grp
 2 13  4 16  6  1  8  5 17 15 10 11  9 18  3 20 14 19 12  7 
 1  1  1  2  1  1  1  1  3  2  1  1  1  1  1  2  2  3  1  1
```

and notice this now gives use the cluster membership (2nd row) for each sample (top row) in the data set.

Next fit the NMDS

```
set.seed(2) ## setting a seed to make this reproducible
ord <- metaMDS(dune)
```

In this example I will colour the points according to cluster membership so I need to define a vector of colours, one per cluster

```
col <- c("red2", "green4", "mediumblue")
```

I can now use `grp` and `col` to produce a vector of colour names for each point (sample) I plot, by indexing into `col` using `grp`. E.g.:

```
R> col[grp]
 [1] "red2"       "red2"       "red2"       "green4"     "red2"      
 [6] "red2"       "red2"       "red2"       "mediumblue" "green4"    
[11] "red2"       "red2"       "red2"       "red2"       "red2"      
[16] "green4"     "green4"     "mediumblue" "red2"       "red2"
```

All the remains is to plot the NMDS ordintion and add the points and a legend. I suppress any plotting in the `plot()` call so I can have more control over adding the points in the next line. The third line just adds a legend.

```
plot(ord, type = "n", display = "sites")
points(ord, col = col[grp], bg = col[grp], pch = 21)
legend("topright", legend = paste("Cluster", 1:3),
       col = col, pt.bg = col, bty = "n", pch = 21)
```

The resulting figure should look like this:

[image: NMDS plot with cluster membership overlain]

---

**Update**: To add convex hulls for each cluster of points to the ordination diagram you can make use of the `ordihull()` function. Continuing the example from above we add the convex hulls as follows

```
ordihull(ord, groups = grp, display = "sites")
```

At which point the figure would look like the one below

[image: adding convex hulls for the clusters]

---

**Note**: **vegan**'s higher-level `plot()` methods are designed purposely to give a quick and dirty display of the ordination and as such don;t accept vectors of colours or plotting characters. instead we expect you to build up your plots flow lower level methods such as the `points()` one I use here.

Comment: Thank you for your excellent answer! I was just wondering....In Primer it is possible to enclose members of a cluster with a boundary (see screen shot above) thereby 'saving' the colour and point shape to convey environmental data say. Is this possible using vegan?

Comment: Yes, see `?ordihull`. I'll add an example.

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks again for your help and also thanks for maintaining a great r package.

Comment: Beautiful solution! Thank you. I altered to show labels, so instead of `points` I used `text(ord, col = col[grp], labels=rownames(ord))`.